# How to delete file from isolated Storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am trying to delete files from isolated storage. But it returning error message to me. I don't know where i did mistake.

```
public void Delete(string folder, string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            string path = folder + "\\" + fileName + ".txt";
            string delPath = folder + "/" + fileName + ".txt";
            MessageBox.Show(delPath);
            if (myIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists(folder))
            {
                if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(delPath))
                {
                    myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(delPath);
                    MessageBox.Show("File is Deleted..!!");
                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("There is no file is exists");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is no Folder is exists");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Please let me know where i did mistake.
Thanks in advance..

Error message:-

[image]

Comment: Try to add `/` before folder

Comment: what Error message or exception you are getting

Comment: Hi all!! Here wit i have attached a Screenshot.. Please refer this..

Comment: Hi @Ku6opr.. Tried your suggestion.. Till now the same error happening..

Comment: In which line of code you getting error ? I go with your code and file deleted successfully.

Comment: Are you really using Windows Phone 7 SDK?

Comment: There is honestly a million reasons why it could be throwing this error. Windows Phone isolated storage has quite possibly the worst error reporting ever.... of all time.... Try this dll. It makes life 1000 times easier for you. Its free and updated constantly EZ_Iso.dll http://www.anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=2

Comment: Hi @Jaihind.. myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(delPath); In this line only i am getting error..

Comment: Hi AMR.. Yes i am using Windows phone 7 SDK. Why this doubt??

Comment: My opinion, your myIsolatedStorage object is already dead. Try covering the method code in using statement: `(using IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())`

Comment: Hi @Olter.. I tries your opinion.. But till now it showing that same error. **using (myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                        {
                            myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(delPath);
                            MessageBox.Show("File is Deleted..!!");
                        }**

Comment: Alright, second attempt. Perhaps, the file, you're trying to delete, is still in usage. Think, can this scenario be possible in your app?

Comment: Hi @Olter. Now it's working. After close the file it's working..!!

Comment: Great. I can write an answer then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, the file, you're trying to delete, is still in usage. Your application should have no open files or references to files that you are trying to delete.